# Why there is no card(register by the host app i develop) show up on Sony SmartEyeGlass

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

I have a GPS navigation app. now i want to use this app as the host app, and display some info on the Sony SmartEyeGlass.

But i am stuck at the first step...

First off, i want to show a card on the Sony SmartEyeGlass. i read the web site
(https://developer.sony.com/2014/09/19/how-to-create-your-first-smarteyeglass-project/)

According to it, i try to modify sample code from HelloLayout and put them into my host app. Anyway,after i launch the host app, nothing change on the SmartEyeGlass.

Any thoughts? im sorry if i didnt make my problem clear. i will be happy to provide more detail if anyone need it.
Please help. i am desperate...
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Those guides are usually incomplete. Try importing an example app and begin from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out, that if I implemented getRequiredNotificationApiVersion() in RegistrationInformation class to return "4", the whole App didn't run any longer.

To exclude this problem, modify the concerned code in your RegistrationInformation class implementation to the following:

private static final int CONTROL_API_VERSION = 4;

```
@Override
public int getRequiredWidgetApiVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
}

@Override
public int getTargetControlApiVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return CONTROL_API_VERSION;
}

@Override
public int getRequiredControlApiVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return CONTROL_API_VERSION;
}

@Override
public int getRequiredSensorApiVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
}

@Override
public int getRequiredNotificationApiVersion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
}
```